# Error: Variable not bound

Tags: oracle, variables

I have some SQL that I am using to query an oracle database. I am attempting to create and reference bound variables, but I am getting the error ORA-01008: not all variables bound.

I have looked into this thoroughly but I cannot see what is wrong with my syntax.

Below is the sql I am using to create the variable, running this gives the error:

```
VARIABLE east_sun_2013 date
BEGIN
:east_sun_2013 := TO_DATE('31/03/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
end;
```

What must I change to successfully create the variable?

Comment: How do you run this code? Are you sure you need namely bind variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE
  east_sun_2013 DATE;
BEGIN
  east_sun_2013 := TO_DATE('31/03/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
END;
```